# Laravel repository no error, blank page

Tags: php, laravel

I've been trying to get the repository pattern working for abstracting the database and for testing purposes. I've been trying for half a day now, to get it working. I only ever get a blank screen (no content sent at all) with no errors.
It seems that using the repository pattern either:

1. Doesn't work on Laravel 4.1
2. Doesn't work on PHP 5.3
3. Or I'm just being stupid

   ```
   class EloquentSurveyRepository implements SurveyRepositoryInterface
   {
       protected $surveyModel;

       public function __construct(Survey $survey)
       {
           $this->surveyModel = $survey;
       }

       public function all()
       {
           return $this->surveyModel->all();
       }
   }

   interface SurveyRepositoryInterface
   {
       public function all();
   }

   class DashboardController extends BaseController
   {

       protected $surveys;

       public function __construct(SurveyRepositoryInterface $survey)
       {
           $this->surveys = $survey;
       }

       public function getDashboardJson()
       {
           $surveys = $this->surveys->all();
           dd($surveys);
       }
   }
   ```

   `App::bind('SurveyRepositoryInterface', 'EloquentSurveyRepository');`

Any help would be grand...

Edit: Survey Model

```
class Survey extends EloquentSurveyRepository {

protected $table = 'lime_surveys';
protected $primaryKey = 'sid';

public function surveyls() {
    return $this->hasOne('Surveyls', 'surveyls_survey_id');
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly url you run? What part of controller is being launched?

Comment: /dashboard/dashboard-json. If I take out the __construct, it works, as in returns content or shows and error.

Comment: I think you should also put here code for `Survey` model, what `all` function for this model does. Is it return anything?

Comment: Added the model. It is using the EloquentORM, or at least should be. The `dd($surveys)` is never being called, and there are no errors thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is your `Survey` model. Now you have:

```
class Survey extends EloquentSurveyRepository {
```

it should rather extend Eloquent:

```
class Visit extends Eloquent {
```

You could also try `debug` to `true` for your environment to get more info (probably you could get here for example `maximum nested function level reached` here).

Comment: I hate Mondays. Can't believe I didn't spot that! Debug is on already, that's why I was getting confused about there being a blank page. Thanks!